# How to analyze data once broken down into gender, race, etc

Tags: anova, t-test, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, multilevel-analysis

I have two conditions, Treatment A, and Treatment B. Participants are randomly assigned to a treatment at the outset. Then I run unpaired t-tests on the data to find any differences. BUT I am also interested in whether the treatment has an effect on specific gender (Male, Female) and race (white, African American, Latino/a, etc.). Right now, I've broken down the data into all Male, all Female, all white, etc. Then I run unpaired t-tests again for Treatment A vs Treatment B on the sub-sample of data.

Is this the correct approach? Should I be doing something like looking at interaction effects instead of doing this? Thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Analysis of variance indeed seems called for. Just using t-tests is a very limited way of analysing your data. But you don't explain your response (outcome, dependent) variable(s), which is the first thing to explain....

Comment: I'm actually not interested in comparing genders and races (e.g., Male vs. Female, white vs. African American, etc.). My understanding is that is what a three-way ANOVA would do. What I want to do is compare WITHIN all Male, then within all Female, Treatment A vs Treatment B. Does an ANOVA still make sense?

Comment: Regardless of whether they are of interest, other controls are still at work. You can't squeeze out single factor effects by ignoring other factors. So, same advice.

Comment: But isn't the whole point of a between-subjects design, so that you can have a large N in both treatments and that in itself controls for those factors?

Comment: I wouldn't summarize experimental design in that way. Even with a good design, just using single t tests will not somehow take into account the variation with other factors. How could it?

Comment: But what analysis technique would I use? For a concrete example, say I just have Treatment A vs Treatment B, and Male/Female. I could do a two-way ANOVA, with factors treatment and gender. But this still doesn't tell me what I want to know, which is whether there is a significant difference between Treatment A vs Treatment B in all Males, and all Females. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes; you need to study a good modern treatment of analysis of variance.  http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Design-Analysis-Experiments-George/dp/047041216X/ is love it or loathe it. You may have to look around for what's congenial in a good library.

Answer (score 3):

Nick Cox already gave a good answer in the comments, but let's summarize it in a formal answer.

1. By analyzing the same dataset with multiple unpaired t-test, you are
   not exactly respecting the experimental design. I'm not sure what it
   would do, but I think you are increasing the chances of Type I
   error. Someone with a stronger statistical background could say if
   I'm wrong here.
2. An ANOVA would better fit your needs. You would have the following list of fixed effects :

Treatment

Gender

Treatment* Gender

Race

Treatment* Race

Treatment* Gender* Race

You are interested in the interactions, but you cannot test the interactions without the main effects.

3. Like Nick Cox, I would suggest reading a basic book about experimental design.

Comment: Thanks, both you and Nick have been helpful. However, I still don't understand one thing. Say I get a significant effect for the fixed effect of "Treatment*Race". This is telling me there is an interaction between the condition and the race of participants. Does this now justify doing post-hoc t-tests on all participants of each individual race across the two treatments?

Comment: You should rather look at a posteriori test such as LSmeans (personnal favorite, but there is other). Easily done with R and SAS.